# binaryToDecimal with no Library Functions

Tags: c, arrays, binary, char

I have to write a C program that reads a character string from binary into an array of characters and the prints out the decimal form.

I almost have it, but I there's a limitation because we are not allowed to use library functions -- only `scanf()` and `printf()`, not `rem`.

Comment: Please, have a look at [How do I ask a good question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: yup exactly that's what i need

Comment: Post your code where "I almost have it".

Answer (score 1):

Since you are looking for an algorithm, here is the general idea:

Read the data into an array of char using fgets.  Verify it has only '0' and '1' characters.  Then, start at the end of the string, and calculate a sum into an int or long or long long (dunno how many bits you have to support).  To calculate the sum, track the digit you are on. Each digit is in binary, and you should know how to convert from one base to another:

Start with the location `l=0` at the end of the string.  When there is a 1 at position `l`, you add 2 to the power of `l` to your sum.  Then, add one to `l`, and backup in the string one position.  repeat until you are at the front of the string.  This way you add the 1's place, the 2's place, the 4's place, the 8's place, etc into the decimal result.

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdint.h>
#include <inttypes.h>

int main(){
    char bits[32+1];
    uint32_t d=0;
    scanf("%32[01]", bits);
    for(int i=0;bits[i];++i){
        d <<= 1;
        if(bits[i]=='1')
            d |= 1;
    }
    printf("%" PRIu32 "\n", d);

    return 0;
}
```